# Cannot find class - Unable to find explicit activity class

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, compiler-errors

Hi how are you? I'm having trouble with 2 activities that I've created in my app, when I try to press the button to open the activity I have this error

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.flixarts.ar.englishnow/activities.simplefuture}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

This is the androidManifest, it's marked with red.

This is the method that opens the activity

```
public void openSimpleFuture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, simplefuture.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

}

I've tried deleting the activities and create it again but this doesn't work, I don't know what's happening, always that I create an activity it has worked fine but now I'm having this trouble with androidmanifest

Comment: can you share what issue you are getting after adding to androidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi Madhav, I've solved it by putting all the activities in the same folder, thanks!